# Is there a way to have one app.service in systemd start multiple independent app.service units?

Tags: command-line, services, systemd, autostart

For example if I had two service files that ran as `type=forking` that start two different java applications and then two service files that run as type=simple running different applications, is there a way to run another service file that would start/stop the other four but the other four can still be used independently?

for example:

```
dataingest-type1.service
dataingest-type2.service
different-dataingest.type3.service
different-dataingest.type4.service
```

All run properly as separate services under systemd.

Could a service, like `dataingest.service`, start/stop the other four?

Also if one of the other services went down and the `dataingest.service` was run again it should start the service again. (basically I tried making a script that runs `systemctl start <list of services>` and set it up as a service, however if one of the services stops and the service start is run again it does not run the script as it thinks the service is running.)

So the `dataingest.service` looked like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Stuff blah blah
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot  
ExecStart=/path/to/little/script.sh start
ExecStop=/path/to/little/script.sh stop
RemainAfterExit=true

[install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The bash script just does one job!

```
#/bin/bash

/bin/systemctl $1 dataingest-type1.service dataingest-type2.service different-dataingest.type3.service different-dataingest.type4.service
```

Obviously if there is a better method.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

This is one uses of [systemd `.targets`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html).

There's already an answer to this question in the StackExchange network at [How to create a virtual systemd service to stop/start several instances together?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283714/how-to-create-a-virtual-systemd-service-to-stop-start-several-instances-together)

Answer (score 1):

So using The link provided by @Mark I could workout what needed to be done.

The main service, dataingest.service, needed to be a target instead so renamed as dataingest.target
The dataingest.target unit had the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Data Ingest Services
Requires=network.target
After=network.target
Wants=dataingest-type1.service dataingest-type2.service different-dataingest.type3.service different-dataingest.type4.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then the individual services had something similar to the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=type x data ingest service
PartOf=dataingest.target

[Service]
Type=......
etc
etc
etc

[Install]
WantedBy=dataingest.target
```

Then systemctl enable dataingest..... followed by a reload.

Now the services can be started individually and also just using the target file.
    sudo systemctl start dataingest.target

Also if one of the services is down the target unit will start the individual service.

Thanks @mark